# Iframe not resizing anymore since timeline update

Tags: facebook, iframe

Since the update to timeline, my resize scripts stopped working on facebook.
This is my code:

CSS:

```
html {

margin:0;
padding:0;
height:1500px;
}

body {
width:520px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:1500px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#555859;
}
```

In the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

In the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1500 });
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
</script>
```

In the app, I've set the Canvas Height to fluid.

Am I missing something important? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the code like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {  
    FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");             
    FB.init({
        appId : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

}
```